# What is the closed form of sum

Tags: real-analysis

What is the closed form of 
$$
\sum^{n}_{i=0}\frac{1}{i+x}
$$
where $n$ is variable?

Comment: There is no known closed form for $x=1$, so there isn't one for a generic $x$.

Comment: Why do you think there is a closed form ?

Comment: $\psi(x + n + 1) - \psi(x)$ where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe because this sum I have got in the steps in my assignment. I don't know what is the formula for this? I'm stuck.

Comment: @MuhammadSinan it may be that it cancels out with other terms in your problem? It doesn't have a nice closed form.

Comment: Sorry and where n is x not n.

Comment: @JohnDoe I also thought that but I don't know why?

Comment: @MuhammadSinan so did you mean $$\sum^{x}_{i=0}\frac{1}{i+x}$$? (the solution still looks the same, $\psi(2x+1)-\psi(x)$. What are you asking in the second comment?

Comment: @JohnDoe no, the sup is n and the index is i

Comment: so what is the formula for this?

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(n,x)=\sum^{n}_{i=0}\frac{1}{i+x}
$$
This sum cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. A closed form requires a special function, namely the digamma function $\psi(x)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

$$\sum^{n}_{i=0}\frac{1}{i+x}=\psi(x+n+1)-\psi(x+1)$$

This formula is easily derived from the series definition of the digamma function, section "Series formula" in the paper linked above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!